# React-scripts@4 Failed to compile because of prettier

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, prettier, react-scripts

Updated `react-scripts` from 3 to 4.0.1 with all underlying packages (react@17, typescript@4.1 and eslint@7.14), now it shows `Failed to compile.` in the console with tons of `prettier` problems like they are errors. Used to run fine before, showing only Eslint warnings. Also if I hit save on any clean file under watch it recompiles fine (but again, used to show Eslint warning, which I would like to see there). Went through their docs and didn't find a way to configure this behavior, can it be?

Comment: If you keep a git repo on your project's folder, try having a look at config files, like `.eslintrc.{js,yml,json}`. Also, you should probably read this: [link](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-4.0.0). If you keep having problems, you may want to add some detail.

Comment: @DarioRodriguez `.eslintrc` had a single line `"extends": [ "react-app", "plugin:prettier/recommended" ]`, I tried different configs from `create-react-app` sources/random articles and all it did is added extra errors to the output, the prettier formatting stuff showing as errors never went away. And why Migrating to v4.0.0 of Eslint, when I already had 6.8 prior to this 

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: @Mohammad Nope, had to give up on upgrading `react-scripts`.